# How to check with Firebug if a JS function is applied

Tags: jquery, firebug

How can I check with **Firebug** if on a certain page a specific JavaScript function - **jQuery based** - is applied?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While Christopher's answer is somewhat correct, many times you won't want to use a tracepoint that interrupts execution and requires manual interaction to resume execution (at that point it's technically a breakpoint).

With Firebug or equivalent browser debug consoles, you can insert tracepoints into your code using `console.log()`. AFAIK, the console object isn't a standard JavaScript/ECMAScript construct, but it's supported in:

- Firefox with [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com) or [Console²](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/console%C2%B2/) installed
- Firefox 4+ [through the Web Developer Tools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Using_the_Web_Console#Opening_the_Web_Console)
- Chrome
- Safari
- IE8+
- Opera 9+
- many other browsers using [Firebug Lite](http://getfirebug.com/firebuglite)

I believe you need to have the console window actually open/enabled in many of these environments before the object is actually accessible, and then there's the issue of browsers which don't support the `window.console` object or having debug code accidentally slip into a production application. But there are many solutions to these problems as well:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/783661/log-to-firefox-error-console-from-javascript
- http://patik.com/blog/complete-cross-browser-console-log/
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/217957/how-to-print-debug-messages-in-the-google-chrome-javascript-console

The point is, there are better ways to debug than just throwing an `alert()` box. And if you've got Firebug installed but aren't yet familiar with Firebug's JavaScript debugging facilities, [this is a good overview](http://getfirebug.com/javascript).

Answer (score 0):

JQuery or not, JavaScript will stop executing code after an error... most of the time on the entire page (There are a few exceptions though). Using Firebug is overkill when you can just toss in an alert("IT WORKS"); at the end of the suspect function. If the popup works, then the function is applied. Giving more information as to exactly *what* function you're referring to would help.